# simple Variable Daclaration

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I can't understand why that variable declaration command doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT rek_pers PROMPT 'Employee name: '
ACCEPT year_sal PROMPT 'Yearly salary: '

VARIABLE vENAME VARCHAR2,vSAL NUMBER

DECLARE
:vENAME := &rek_pers;
:vSAL := &year_sal;

BEGIN  
UPDATE Emp SET Emp.Sal = vSAL
Where Emp.Ename = vENAME;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I receive answer:
Bind Variable "vENAME" is NOT DECLARED

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have several errors.

variables should be defined seperatley, not with commas. i.e.:

```
VARIABLE vENAME VARCHAR2
VARIABLE vSAL NUMBER
```

secondly this is invalid syntax:

```
:vENAME := &rek_pers;
:vSAL := &year_sal;
```

it should just be simply (without the `variable` defines needed):

```
DECLARE
vSAL Emp.Sal%type := &year_sal;
vENAME Emp.Ename%type := '&rek_pers';
BEGIN  
UPDATE Emp SET Emp.Sal = vSAL
Where Emp.Ename = vENAME;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

if you did want to assign a variable, the correct way would be:

```
VARIABLE vENAME VARCHAR2(200)
VARIABLE vSAL NUMBER
EXEC :vSAL := &year_sal;
EXEC :vENAME := '&rek_pers';
BEGIN  
UPDATE Emp SET Emp.Sal = :vSAL
Where Emp.Ename = :vENAME;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

(p.s. don't forget the length of the varchar2)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use colon by declaring the variable.
try:

> DECLARE
>
> vENAME := &rek_pers;
>
> vSAL := &year_sal;